# Replace string in <body> with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with a seemingly simple task. Working on a WP website, I have a plugin that is outputting the following string

```
..." />
```

just after the body tag. The plugin is not optional, and I'd like to hide this for the moment, until it can be fixed. So how does one find and delete that string?

I tried this, but it returns a pile of text:

```
$("body").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace('..." />', '');
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

Comment: The best way to to that is editing the plugin...

Comment: `$("body")` is not an array so `each()` is not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need

```js
$(function() {
  var html = $("body").html();
  $("body").html(html.replace('..." />', ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you should add some flags on that like `multiple line`

Comment: That's not a regex, but you may be right...It's possible that this code doesn't work...But I don't have the HTML of the OP

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing ")". Aside from that, it does work, but only if I remove the '>' from search. Apparently it is not matching that. In other words, it will replace '..." /' but not '..." />'